# Can I program set env use bat then emit a process?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd

Think about :I want to write a program use cmake auto compile some frequently library(zlib,png....and so on)

in cmd Console,I use .bat set up Environment.

sample :`cmd /k "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

then `cmake -G....cmake --build ....`

Now I want Write a program(not .bat file),setup environment  with .bat file.and then work as fine as in cmd Console.

(I can write a .bat file auto do it,but I want to write a exe do it.....)

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work. The batch file sets up the environment of that `CMD` process, not your executable.

Your batch file idea is the better solution, as it is run by CMD.